# Alamofire and JSONAPI

Tags: swift, alamofire, json-api

I'm trying to figure out how to use Alamofire with a JSONAPI datasource.  I'm trying to `POST` some data.  The code below doesn't work.  I'm learning HTTP requests and JSON as I go, so there might be other issues with the code.  Would really appreciate any help.

```
        let parameters = [
        "data" : [
            "type" : "notes",
            "attributes" : [
                "relevant-date" : date,
                "details" : self.textField.text
            ],
            "relationships" : [
                "child" : [
                    "data" : [
                        "type" : "children",
                        "id" : self.passedChildID!
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, "url", parameters: parameters, encoding: .JSON)
    .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
        if let value = response.result.value {
            let json = JSON(value)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved with a server side filter and the updated code is as follows.

```
let parameters = [
        "auth_token" : "test",
        "filter" : [
            "phone-number" : self.PhoneNumber!
        ]
    ]
Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL)
        .responseJSON { (response) -> Void in
                print("Request \(response.request)")
         }
```

**EDIT**

I *really* solved it with code from the Alamofire Github page.  I had to add the 2 separate headers that are identified below.

```
let URL = NSURL(string: "https://httpbin.org/post")!
let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL)
mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = "POST"

let parameters = ["foo": "bar"]

do {mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = try     NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
    } catch {
        // No-op
}

    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/vnd.api+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")  //one header
    mutableURLRequest.setValue("application/vnd.api+json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")  //second header

Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
```

Comment: sorry I have a problem and I want to set json api model with Alamofire response , do you know any way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look at the excellent Spine library: https://github.com/wvteijlingen/Spine It provides a convenient Swift interface for interacting with a JSONAPI backend and will help guide you as you learn.

Comment: this is not a good library for me :( I couldn't use it as well, Do you have any offer ?

Comment: In the 3+ years since I wrote this comment, it looks like the Spine library has been deprecated & then forked, then the fork hasn't been updated lately. So I'd say this library is no longer the solution for JSONAPI Swift implementation.